# module' object has no attribute 'register_namespace' in python 2.6.6

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import sys, os

ET.register_namespace("foo.a","http://example.com/mphg/")
ET.register_namespace("foo.b","http://example.com/abcd/")

tree = ET.parse(web.xml)
root = tree.getroot()

root.set("xmlns:foo.c","http://example.com/lkag/")

tree.write(file)
```

while running this in python 2.6.6 I am getting

> Attribute_Error: module' object has no attribute 'register_namespace'...

Answer (score 4):

You're importing `xml.etree.ElementTree as ET` then you're using `ElementTree` instead of `ET`.

Try replacing it with this

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import sys, os

# Replace ElementTree with ET
ET.register_namespace("foo.a","http://example.com/mphg/") 
ET.register_namespace("foo.b","http://example.com/abcd/")

tree = ET.parse(web.xml) root = tree.getroot()

root.set("xmlns:foo.c","http://example.com/lkag/")

tree.write(file)
```

Comment: Even after using ET inplace of Element .. I am getting same error ie; Attribute_Error: module' object has no attribute 'register_namespace'
and also modified the question